# Passing HANDLE as an argument when opening a com port in C/C++ in Windows

Tags: c, windows, serial-port

So I have something like as follows:

In my main.c

```
HANDLE *hCom;
success = openport(hCom);
ReadFile(hCom......)   // This Produces Garbled Results
```

The openport() function:

```
 int openport(HANDLE *hCom)
 {
     hCom = CreateFile(......)
     ReadFile(hCom......)   // This Produces Good Results
     return 0;
 }
```

When I do read commands inside of my openport() function everything works fine, but if I use hCom in my main.c I get garbage.

My question is, what am I doing wrong/missing?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: *"// This Produces Good Results"* - not if you have `STRICT` defined (which you should). `hCom = CreateFile(...)` where `hCom` is `HANDLE*` shouldn't even *compile*. `CreateFile` returns `HANDLE`, not `HANDLE*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a Windows issue, it's a basic C issue: you're misusing the pointers.  The value you pass to ReadFile has never been initialized, it is random garbage.

The code should look like this:

```
HANDLE hCom;   // declare a HANDLE (not a pointer to one)
success = openport(&hCom);   // pass the function a pointer to the HANDLE
ReadFile(hCom......);   // use the HANDLE

int openport(HANDLE *hCom)   // We receive a pointer
{
  *hCom = CreateFile(......)   // Write to the variable being pointed to
  ReadFile(*hCom......)
  return 0;
}
```

or, equivalently (though less elegantly):

```
HANDLE *hCom;   // declare a pointer to a HANDLE
hCom = malloc(sizeof(HANDLE)); // allocate space for it
success = openport(hCom);   // pass the function the pointer
ReadFile(*hCom......);   // use the pointer
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `hCom = CreateFile(......)` will create HANDLE or ...., you can using `hCom = CreateFile(......)` in main.c.

```
HANDLE *hCom;
hCom = CreateFile(......)
success = openport(hCom);
ReadFile(hCom......)
```